# Rmarkdown Beamer presentation: Adding buttons and shortcuts in to jump to other slides

Tags: latex, rstudio, r-markdown, beamer

Does anyone know how to use shortcuts or buttons to jump to other slides?  Hyperref I think is the latex command.

Example output:

[image]

Comment: Can someone please explain why this is a bad question?

Comment: I don't understand the question, when you export it out in pdf you can use usual shortcut to do it (depending on your pdf reader obviously). So I don't get your question. Can you provide more details?

Comment: I mean I want to create hyperlink buttons on slides that can go to like slides that are only shown if the audience asks me a question related to the slide, otherwise the presentation continues as the layout is intended.  Also buttons to jump around ON the slides.

Comment: As opposed to part of the table of contents

Answer (score 4):

One possible answer to your question is in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269577/beamer-hyperlink-to-specific-slide-in-frame)

it's said to use:

`\hypertarget{label}{\beamerbutton{some text}}`

to place the target then use elsewhere the command:

`\hyperlink{label}{\beamerbutton{go to slide}}`

to activate a button that will take you to the slide previously targeted.

Comment: And the trick people use, is to put these slides at the very end of the presentation so we only reach them through the button, correct?

Comment: Do you know how to make the button appear at the very bottom of the slide?

Comment: if you use the command `\btVFill` before the button it will appear at the very bottom, [more details](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54180/how-do-i-write-something-at-the-end-of-the-slide-in-beamer)

Comment: Do you know how to hide the target button on the new slide when you link to it?  Like it appears as a dead button when you jump to target...

Comment: Later, found better answer: Use \label{xx} and hyperlink, screw hypertarget!